# AxHost+ConnectionPointCookie.Finalize Throws exception - Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

Tags: c#, winforms, garbage-collection

We are getting the below error in our application some times and we are not able to reproduce this issue manually. It looks like it is coming from GC but I am not sure what is causing it.
Any help is appreciated.

Type: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean)
System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])
System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Post(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback, System.Object)
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+ConnectionPointCookie.Finalize()

Comment: please post the calling site of the `BeginInvoke` method. We need code to understand your problem better. are you trying to populate a control before the `InitializeComponents` call ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to marshal to the UI Thread using a Control instance that the AxHost is in the process of disconnecting (the Control is disposed - the AxHost posts to the synch context the unadvise procedure, unless it's the AppDomain that is being unloaded). It could be a Thread that is still working while a Container is closed and nothing informs it about it